# Understanding "warning: use of `#[derive]` with a raw pointer" warning

Tags: rust

#### Summary

I'm trying to understand what the following warning means and what the best way to silence it is if there's not an actual problem with my code.

```
warning: use of `#[derive]` with a raw pointer, #[warn(raw_pointer_derive)] on by default
```

#### Details

I am mostly interested in understanding what this warning means, but the details of why I am seeing it are that I have some library code written in Go and I have exported that code and want to call it from Rust. As of version 1.5, Go has an option to generate a C interface. This includes a generated header file that contains the declaration:

```
typedef struct { void *data; GoInt len; GoInt cap; } GoSlice;
```

I also have an exported function in the generated C file that uses this `struct`:

```
extern GoUint64 Foo(GoSlice p0);
```

To call this function from Rust I create a `struct` as follows:

```
#[repr(C)]
#[derive(Copy, Clone)]
pub struct GoSlice {
    pub data: *const u64,
    pub len:  c_long,
    pub cap:  c_long,
}
```

I also import the function as:

```
extern fn Foo(data: GoSlice) -> c_ulong;
```

Then when I use the function I do something like:

```
fn call_foo(arr: &[u64]) -> u64 {
    let res: u64;
    let go_slice = GoSlice {
        data: arr.as_ptr(),
        len: arr.len() as i64,
        cap: arr.len() as i64
    };
    unsafe {
        res = Foo(go_slice);
    }
    return res;
}
```

So I think that I need the `go_slice` object to be copied, which is why I added the `#[derive(Copy, Clone)]`, but I'm not certain whether the warning means there is a real problem or not.  If not, I'd like to silence it if possible, and if there's an actual problem then I want to fix my code.

I'm using rust nightly and this warning happens with `rustc 1.4.0-nightly (20a8412e0 2015-08-28)`

Answer (score 3):

Basically, the warning is just "this looks suspicious: can you really clone this struct by just copying the raw pointer?".  If you're sure what you're doing is actually right, you can just implement Copy and Clone by hand.

In this particular case... you probably shouldn't be trying to manipulate a Go slice from Rust code in the first place.  You probably want to pass in a raw pointer from the Rust side, and convert it to a slice in Go code.  Otherwise, the next person who comes along to modify the Go code is going to assume that the lifetime of the slice is managed by the Go garbage collector.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "You probably want to pass in a raw pointer from the Rust side."  I'm trying to see if I can use the C interface that Go exposes, so in theory the Go library function doesn't know whether it is called from Rust, C, Python, etc.  The interface that Go exposes has the GoSlice struct which takes the raw pointer that it will then use internally.  At least I think that is what is happening, I'm still figuring things out hence my question.

Comment: What I was trying to say is that you should change the Go library so it doesn't expose a function which takes a slice as an argument.